# Given that $\frac{n!}{(n-x)!}+\frac{x!}{(x-n)!}=48$, find the value of $\binom{n+4}{x-3}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations, factorial

I am struggling with the following:

Given that $\frac{n!}{(n-x)!}+\frac{x!}{(x-n)!}=48$, find the value of     $~^{n+4}C_{x-3}$.

Any help with the method would be great. The answer is 8.

Comment: What a weird question. We immediately get $n = x$ for it to be well-defined.... o_O

Comment: Great point, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for this to make sense both $n-x$ and $x-n$ must be nonnegative, which implies that $x = n$. Thus $2n! = 48 \implies x = n = 4$.

Comment: Thanks for fleshing that one out.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

**Case**$\#1:$ What if $n=x$

**Case**$\#2:$ If $n>x,$ $$\dfrac1{(x-n)!}=0$$

$$\dfrac{n!}{(n-x)!}=n(n-1)\cdots \{n-(x+1)\}$$

Check with $n-x=1,2,3,4$ as for $n-x=5, 5!>48$

**Case**$\#3:$ Similarly  if $n<x$

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10124/the-factorial-of-1-2-3